# Can I create rich, dynamic "Implementation Notes" in swagger?

Tags: java, swagger

I'm currently using ApiOperation annotation for documenting my web services methods in the "Implementation Notes" section:

```
@ApiOperation(
    value = "Searches for information",
    notes = "This service searches for information"
)
public Response getInformation(...)
```

I want to enhance my notes now to use properties files, information from a database, etc.  I want it to be rich and dynamic.

So, let's say I have a POJO that contains information from the database:

```
@Entity
public class SortColumnField {
    @Id
    @Column
    private String fieldName;
    @Column
    private String fieldDescription;
}
```

Is there something that would allow me to generate swagger documentation from objects such as this?

Answer (score -1):

You have two choices for doing this.

First, the notes section supports markdown, specifically github-flavored.  You can have fairly rich information in that section and most tools will render it correctly.

Next, the [Operation Object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#operation-object) supports a field called `externalDocs`.  While not rendered in Swagger-UI, you can easily fork the UI to reference your complex documents which may not fit in the structure that is rendered in the standard tools.

Comment: The notes section cannot be dynamic though, correct?  It just supports a constant.  Also, externalDocs is just a link on the swagger documentation page, right?  I'm looking for something that I can embed in the page...otherwise I'd probably just use my own documentation.